# Unity Game Programming

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine

I have a GUI Text object on my scene and i want it to show the remaining lives that i have left for the play. I cant seem to get this to work for some reason. I have the code below, could someone help me please?!

```
// the sound to play when the player is shot
public var shotSound:AudioClip;

// the number of lives
public var lives:int = 3;


/**
    Player has been shot
*/
function Shot () 
{
    // play the shot audio clip
    audio.PlayOneShot(shotSound);

    // reduce lives
    lives--;

    // reload the level if no lives left
    if (lives == 0)
    {
        // destroy the crosshair
        Destroy(GetComponent(CrossHair));

        // add the camera fade (black by default)
        iTween.CameraFadeAdd();

        // fade the transparency to 1 over 1 second and reload scene once complete
        iTween.CameraFadeTo(iTween.Hash("amount", 1, "time", 1, "oncomplete", "ReloadScene", "oncompletetarget", gameObject));
    }
}


/**
    Reload the scene
*/ 
function ReloadScene()
{
    // reload scene
    Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Details would help those who want to help.

Comment: basically the GUI text on the scene does not update. it stays as the generic text it is set. I used (guiText.text = "Lives Remaining:  "+lives;) code in the update function and made it a component of the GUI Text but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Is there any chance that you can post some (any) of the code that you've tried? I don't even see an `update()` present in this code, nor any reference to `guiText`. Maybe I'm missing something, but I think more information is needed if anyone is to lend a hand with this one.

Comment: there is no update function in the code, would i need to put this in and then put the (guiText.text = "Lives Remaining: "+lives;) within that? I think i did try this however it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Create GUIText object by going to GameObject->Create Other->GUI Text. Now drag this to playerLives field of below script in inspector panel. It should work.

```
// the sound to play when the player is shot
public var shotSound:AudioClip;

public var GUIText playerLives;

// the number of lives
public var lives:int = 3;

function OnGUI ()
{
    playerLives.Text = lives.ToString();
}
/**
    Player has been shot
*/
function Shot () 
{
    // play the shot audio clip
    audio.PlayOneShot(shotSound);

    // reduce lives
    lives--;

    // reload the level if no lives left
    if (lives == 0)
    {
        // destroy the crosshair
        Destroy(GetComponent(CrossHair));

        // add the camera fade (black by default)
        iTween.CameraFadeAdd();

        // fade the transparency to 1 over 1 second and reload scene once complete
        iTween.CameraFadeTo(iTween.Hash("amount", 1, "time", 1, "oncomplete", "ReloadScene", "oncompletetarget", gameObject));
    }
}


/**
    Reload the scene
*/ 
function ReloadScene()
{
    // reload scene
    Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
}
```